# Retrieve Information from txt File possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I try to make my App as simple as possible. For this i want to store a .txt file with names on a Server and then populate a TableView with this txt. Inside the txt there should be just names, one at each line. Is it possible to get this txt into a tableview? I would use a plist file but the app will be updated by a person which is not used to programming and plist files.
Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read a simple textfile in whole into a NSString, split it by the linefeeds into a NSArray and there is your datasource for the tableview. You could make it editable with NSMutableArray instead, later convert it to NSString again and write it back to a file.